# Why is Beis Hillel before Beis Shammai in Mishna Sukkah?

Tags: masechet-sukkah, beis-shammai, beis-hillel

Based on the [Gemara Eruvin (13b)](https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.13b.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that says

> מִפְּנֵי
> מָה זָכוּ בֵּית הִלֵּל לִקְבּוֹעַ הֲלָכָה כְּמוֹתָן? מִפְּנֵי
> שֶׁנּוֹחִין וַעֲלוּבִין הָיוּ, וְשׁוֹנִין דִּבְרֵיהֶן וְדִבְרֵי בֵּית
> שַׁמַּאי, וְלֹא עוֹד אֶלָּא **שֶׁמַּקְדִּימִין דִּבְרֵי בֵּית שַׁמַּאי
> לְדִבְרֵיהֶן** - Beis Hillel was privileged to have the
> halakha established in accordance with their opinion because they were agreeable and forbearing, showing restraint when
> affronted, and when they taught the halacha they would teach both
> their own statements and the statements of Beis Shammai. **Moreover,
> when they formulated their teachings and cited a dispute, they
> said the statements of Beit Shammai before their own statements, in
> deference to Beit Shammai.**

My father asked me why the [Mishna Sukkah (3:9)](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sukkah.3.9?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en) brings Beis Hillel *before* Beis Shammai:

וְהֵיכָן הָיוּ מְנַעְנְעִין, בְּהוֹדוּ לַה' תְּחִלָּה וָסוֹף, וּבְאָנָּא ה' הוֹשִׁיעָה נָּא, **דִּבְרֵי בֵית הִלֵּל. וּבֵית שַׁמַּאי אוֹמְרִים,** אַף בְּאָנָּא ה' הַצְלִיחָה נָא

Comment: Possibly because the mishna is more concise in this order, since בית שמאי is בית הלל+, so the משנה can use אף.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the תוי"ט addresses this question in the second part of his comment [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_Yom_Tov_on_Mishnah_Sukkah.3.9.3?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he):

> **ובית שמאי אומרים אף באנא הצליחה נא**. ...ולפי שב"ש באו להוסיף על דברי בית הלל. סדרם אחריהם וכן במשנה ה' פ"ד דגיטין. שבאו ב"ש להשיב על דברי ב"ה משא"כ בשאר דוכתי בכל הגמרא. ועיין משנה ב' פ"ב דחגיגה ומשנה ג' פ"ק דעדיות:

> Because Beis Shammai is coming to add onto the words of Beis Hillel they were set (in the Mishna) after (Beis Shamai). And so too in Gitin 4 5, where Beis Shammai is coming to answer onto the words of Beis Hillel, unlike the rest of the Gemara. And see Chagiga 2 2 and Eduyos 1 3.

Answer (score 1):

The Ben Yehoyada Sukkah (37b) [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Ben%20Yehoyada%20on%20Sukkah%2037b:1) on this Mishna:

> וְהֵיכָן הָיוּ מְנַעְנְעִין? בְּ"הוֹדוּ לַה'" תְּחִלָּה וָסוֹף,
> וּ"בְאָנָּא ה' הוֹשִׁיעָה נָא", דִּבְרֵי בֵּית הִלֵּל. אף על גב דבכל
> דוכתא נקיט דברי בית שמאי קודם, הכא נקיט דברי בית הלל קודם, ללמד דבית
> הלל נקטו כן לכתחילה אבל בדיעבד אם לא נענע כאן אלא נענע בְּ'אָנָּא ה'
> הַצְלִיחָה נָא' יצא ידי חובתו, ואם היה נקיט דברי בית שמאי קודם היה
> צריך לשנות בדברי בית הלל הכי 'ובית הלל אומרים לא ינענע אלא באנא ה'
> הושיעה נא' ולשון זה נראה דמעכב גם בדיעבד אם לא נענע באנא ה' הושיעה נא
> ואפילו אם היה שונה ובית הלל אומרים באנא ה' הושיעה נא עם כל זה כיון
> דקדמו דברי בית שמאי הוה משמע דבאו לאפוקי מבית שמאי לגמרי גם בדיעבד

If Beis Hillel's opinion was written after Beis Shammai's in the Mishna (i.e., "Do not shake the daled minim by Ana Hashem Hatzlicha Nah"), then it would imply Beis Hillel holds one who shakes for hatzlicha nah would not be yotzei b'dieved; however, that is not true. Beis Hillel holds one would still fulfill the mitzvah b'dieved even by shaking for "Ana Hashem Hatzlicha Nah."